# Json.data to Angular Stacked Bar chart

Tags: angularjs, json, charts, stackedbarseries

I am trying to push some data into Angular Stacked Bar chart array. Anyone who could advice me with this?

I have a function

```
myService.getWorkload().then(function(res) {
  json = res.data;
});
```

Then I have a Stacked Bar chart:

```
$scope.chart = {
    "series": []
    "data": [[],[]],
    }
```

And JSON:

`[
  {
    "label1": 2,
    "label2": 3,
    "label3": 4,
    "label4": 5
  },
  {
    "label1": 0,
    "label2": 2,
    "laber3": 4,
    "label4": 6
  }
]`

How do I get the JSON key and the value into the series[key] and data[value]?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this chart library. The examples in them for bar chart will be really helpful

http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Comment: I am using the library you mentioned. In fact the Stackedbar chart is not a part of the page you pointing out. But it is a part of the Github repository. (Just letting you know in case you didn't really study this library enough.) You answer is not relevant to my question.

Comment: Can you please share the code on how you access the chart library from Angular service ?